# JPA persistence.xml I want it to connect to MariaDB but it always connects to hsqldb

Tags: hibernate, apache-tomee, persistence.xml, jpa-2.2, tomee-8

I have a java webapp,

`persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
         version="2.2">

<persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/qltb"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="my_passwowrd"/>

        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I create a simple `Bottle` `@Entity` class, which contains only an id and a String property.

When I run this webapp, I see in the log that it was processing `my-persistence-unit` but an exception was thrown:

```
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: my-persistence-unit
...]

... // Some lines are skipped


org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
create table Bottle (
   id bigint not null,
    color varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

.... // Some lines are skipped
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: ENGINE : line: 6
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Why JPA is connecting to hsqldb instead of MariaDB as declared in persistence.xml?

Additional information: I am using TomEE 8.0.0 M1

Comment: I have only `persistence.xml`, `web.xml` and a `pom.xml`, there is not any `properties` file. `web.xml` is created by maven and is untouched.

Comment: Java source code contains only `Bottle` class, which is the `@Entity` class

Comment: If you look at whatever log and full stack trace you should see what code causes "it" (i.e TomEE) to connect. i.e where the EMF is instantiated and by what code, and with which persistence unit.

Answer (score 1):

I added `resources.xml` into `WEB-INF` (and NOT `META-INF/context.xml`) with following content and now it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <Resource id="myDataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        jdbcDriver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl = jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/qltb
        userName = root
        password = password
        maxActive = 20
</Resource>
```

TomEE Resource configuration: http://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html

I still don't know where the relationship between `persistence.xml` and `resources.xml` is documented (in this case). I don't even need a `<jta-data-source>` tag in `persistence.xml`

Comment: I think tomee takes the available data source ( myDatasource ) .

Comment: I also can't figure out the relationship between `persistence.xml` and `resources.xml`.